# What's the point behind passing functions as arguments to other functions?

Tags: language-concepts

It's a rather general purpose question and not specific to any one language. I don't quite understand the point behind passing a function as an argument to another function. I understand that if a function, say, `foo1()` needs to use some result returned by another function `foo2()`, why can't the values returned/updated by `foo2()` be passed to `foo1()` as is? Or in another scenario, why can't the `foo2()` be called within `foo1()` with its results being used therein? 
Also what happens under the hood when a `foo2()` is passed as an argument to `foo1()`? Is `foo2()` executed prior to `foo1()`?

Comment: Take a look at this, it may be useful: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/253868/passing-functions-into-other-functions-as-parameters-bad-practice

Comment: Basically without reiterating all that link, it's necessary for higher-order functions. [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) and [reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) are common examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you pass a function `foo2` to a function `foo1` in cases where multiple evaluations of `foo2` will be necessary - and you perhaps don't know in advance what parameters will be used for each call of `foo2`, so you couldn't possibly perform the calls yourself in advance.

I think that a `sort()` function/method on lists might be the best concrete example.  Consider a list of People - you might reasonably want to sort them alphabetically by name, or numerically by age, or by geographical distance from a given point, or many other possible orders.  It would hardly be practical to include every such ordering as built-in options to `sort()`: the usual approach taken by languages is to allow the caller to provide a function as a parameter, that defines the ordering between items of the list.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons:

Dependency injection: if you pass a method that in production will use a database call, and you use it with different parameters, you could substitute it with some mock when unit testing.

Map, filter, reduce: you could apply the same method to a list of parameters, to map it, filter it or reduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually to provide callbacks, or to separate interface from implementation.  Look up the following:

  1. Dependency Injection,
  2. Callbacks,
  3. Anonymous Functions (aka Lambdas),
  4. PIMPL
  etc

Take a look at this book where it is used extensively in developing TDD with C:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Driven-Development-Embedded-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/193435662X